# Finding error in this code

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[REQUISITION]
(
    [COMPANY] [int] NULL,
    [WAVE] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FROM_LOC] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [TO_LOC] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [PRODNUM] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [PRODDESC] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [QTY] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_REQUISITION_WAVE1]  DEFAULT ('SP'),

     CONSTRAINT [PK_REQUISITION1] 
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([FROM_LOC] ASC, [TO_LOC] ASC, [PRODNUM] ASC, [WAVE] ASC)
               WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
                     IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
                     ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: A column of type `INT` cannot have a default value of `SP` ......

Comment: And string columns with a length of 3 or 5 should really better be `char(3)` and `char(5)` instead of `varchar` (which always adds at least 2 byte overhead to every entry)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set the lenth of yours varchar fields.

Use this one:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[REQUISITION]    Script Date: 14.01.2016 

21:46:58 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[REQUISITION](
    [COMPANY] [int] NULL,
    [WAVE] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [FROM_LOC] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [TO_LOC] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [PRODNUM] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [PRODDESC] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [QTY] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_REQUISITION1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FROM_LOC] ASC,
    [TO_LOC] ASC,
    [PRODNUM] ASC,
    [WAVE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[REQUISITION] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_REQUISITION_WAVE1]  DEFAULT ('SP') FOR [QTY]
GO
```

Comment: I am getting error here

WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 

ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY]

GO SET ANSI_PADDING OFF

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[REQUISITION](
 [COMPANY] [int] NULL,
 [WAVE] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [FROM_LOC] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
 [TO_LOC] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
 [PRODNUM] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
 [PRODDESC] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [QTY] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_REQUISITION_WAVE1]  DEFAULT ('SP'),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_REQUISITION1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [FROM_LOC] ASC,
 [TO_LOC] ASC,
 [PRODNUM] ASC,
 [WAVE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF

Comment: Where is here. What is the error message? Please provide more info

Comment: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Line 15: Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Thank you

Comment: Put a space after the )WITH like ") WITH" and try again. What type of DBMS you are using? Looks like MySQL

Comment: SQLSERVER 2000
Thank you

Comment: No its not working Andreas. I am getting here
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: Andreas your update is 
 
 
Put a space after the )WITH like ") WITH" and try again. What type of DBMS you are using? Looks like MySQL 
Can you tell me in detail please.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to execute the query? Please do not remove any line breaks!